# Access to USB Device in native code

Tags: android

I have written a code in java which request for USB permission and pull data from usb device after permission is granted. Now I want to write the same code in native c. I checked android ndk platform header files and find three USB related files. But I don't know if native code can request permission for USB device. Is it possible to pass USB Device as an ExraParcelable and get it in native activity?